# @user vs current_user in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm still kind of new to Rails and I'm not understanding why I cant access `@user` in a custom view template. But it works perfectly fine when it's being called in one of the standard actions like `show, edit, update, destroy`

for example I created this route

```
get 'mygroups' => 'users#mygroups'
```

In the users_controller I added

```
  def mygroups
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

then I created a new view template called mygroups.html.erb under Users and added this to the view

```
<%= @user.first_name %>
```

I get an error saying

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

I have a current_user object though that I can use in the view without any problem.

```
<% current_user.first_name %>
```

I just don't understand why I can't load the `@user` object in my `mygroups` method to get it to show in the mygroups.html.erb template.  Are there any drawbacks to using current_user instead of `@user` ? how come the users controller has show, update, etc... loading @user by calling `@user = User.find(params[:id])` but it doesn't in my method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing when you're accessing the `mygroups` route, you're not passing in an id, hence the error message saying it's blank. The default CRUD user actions (show, update etc) will all have routes setup to expect the id, and any links to those actions (or form URLs etc) will carry through the user id in question.

The difference between `@user` and `current_user` in this sense, is that `current_user` is generally your authenticated user, based on the current session. However, `@user` in the users controller is the user being acted upon. Imagine that you have an app where your `current_user` is some kind of admin, and that admin is allowed to create, read, update and destroy other users. The `@user` being acted upon is a specific user, rather than the currently authenticated one.

Try accessing your `mygroups` route with an id, `/mygroups?id=USER_ID` if you're sure you want it to work for *any* user - if you only want it to work for the current user, lose the `User.find` lookup and just use current_user instead.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you.  you were correct I was not passing in the id when accessing the route.  I changed it to ` get 'mygroups/:id' => 'users#mygroups' ` and then did a mygroups/1 and the page loaded.  Also thanks for the explanation about current_user.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is almost always (99% of the time) the current logged in user. This method is defined (behind the scenes in your case) in ActionController.

Your error message is indicative of not having an `id` param present, whether by POSTed parameters or parameters in your query string.

Since you're new to Rails, you may find the classic Rails Tutorial a great and beneficial read. https://www.railstutorial.org/